# CSS: Three columns with center column moving down when it's too wide

Tags: css, multiple-columns, flexbox

I'm trying to lay out a header.  It's got back and forward arrows on the left and right sides, and a title in the middle.  When the title is too wide, I want it to appear below the arrows... Not sure how to do this!  I tried messing around with flex-box, but I'm not that great at it.

Visual:

```
              <     Title     >
```

Turns into:

```
              <               >
              Super Wide Title!
```

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/wulftone/pen/KHkud

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without flexbox if you don't mind reordering the html and using some floats. Here is [a codepen showing that](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjxeF). It uses this structure:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="one">1</li>
  <li class="three">3</li>
  <li class="two">2</li>
</ul>
```

**Key CSS**

This is just the key css to get the functionality you seek of having the center drop down.

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.one {
  float: left;
}

.three {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that ended up being easier than I thought.

Here's the HTML(slim):

```
ul
  li.one 1
  li.three 3
  li.two Super Long Title!
```

And the CSS(sass):

```
ul
  padding: 0
  margin: 0
  color: white
  font-weight: bold
  font-size: 3em
  text-align: center
  list-style: none

li
  background: tomato
  padding: 5px
  width: 200px
  height: 150px
  line-height: 150px

.three
  float: right

.one
  float: left

li.two
  width: auto
  display: inline-block
```

http://codepen.io/wulftone/pen/GbLHI

Good old floats saved the day again!  I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You beat me answering your own question by 45 secs!